# How to change only the PlotLegend size

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I have Plot such as

```
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 1020, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3],
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Meow1", "Meow2", "Meow3"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 50}], {Right, Bottom}]]
```

[image]

But I want to only increase the plot legend bar such as (I used Paint)
[image]

Any advice to increase the plot legend bar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative approach to post-process `Plot` output to make the legend lines thick:

```
ClearAll[makeThick, postProcess]
makeThick[t_: 15] := RawBoxes[Replace[ToBoxes@#, 
     LineBox[x_] :> {AbsoluteThickness[t], LineBox[x]}, Infinity]] &;
postProcess[t_: 15] := # /. leg_LineLegend :> (makeThick[t][leg]) &;
```

Example:

```
plt = Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> (Hue /@ RandomReal[1, {3}]), Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3],
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"Meow1", "Meow2", "Meow3"}, 
      LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 10}}, 
      LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}], {Right, Bottom}]];

Row[{plt, postProcess[]@plt}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

```
 legend = LineLegend[Thread[Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; 3]], 
      AbsoluteThickness[10]]], {"Meow1", "Meow2", "Meow3"}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> Large, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and use it as the setting for `PlotLegends` in `Plot` as:

```
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 1020, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, {Right, Bottom}]]
```