# Legends appear fainter and dull

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

The Legends(dashing) in the following plot appear dull. I want to make those dashes in the Legends slightly bold.

```
 P1 = Plot[{Sin[ t], Cos[ t], Tan[ t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashing[None], Thickness[0.005]}, {Red, 
     Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[0.005]}, {Green, Dashing[Small], 
     Thickness[0.005]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"sin", "cos", "tan for b=1"}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {{20, 10}}], Top]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not the most elegant solution, but if I have understood your question correctly, does the job.

```
legend = With[{t = 0.02},
   LineLegend[{
     Directive[Blue, Dashing[None], Thickness[t]],
     Directive[Red, Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[t]], 
     Directive[Green, Dashing[Small], Thickness[t]]},
    {"sin", "cos", "tan for b=1"},
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{40, 10}}
    ]
   ];

Plot[
 {Sin[t], Cos[t], Tan[t]}, {t, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Blue, Dashing[None], Thickness[0.005]},
   {Red, Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[0.005]},
   {Green, Dashing[Small], Thickness[0.005]}
   },
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Top]
 ]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Oh great. Thanks @Pinti.

Comment: @Jee No problem. Please check also ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Using a slightly modified version of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147435/125),

```
ClearAll[makeThick, postProcess]
makeThick[t_: 3] := RawBoxes[Replace[ToBoxes@#, 
     LineBox[x_] :> {AbsoluteThickness[t], CapForm["Butt"], LineBox[x]}, Infinity]] &;

postProcess[t_: 3] := # /. leg_LineLegend :> (makeThick[t][leg]) &;

postProcess[] @ P1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]